# React native TextInput gets cleared while typing in android

Tags: android, input, react-native

I have been following react native tutorials on udemy recently and came across a problem on Android v6.0.

I have a custom `TextInput` component called `Input` included in `LoginForm.js` and whenever I type in the input field the entire text gets cleared. I suspect the problem is due to the `value` property included in `LoginForm.js`, because when I remove this it seems to work fine.

I haven't been able to fix this problem. Any help is appreciated!

**LoginForm.js**

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = { email: '' };

    render() {
        return (
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input
                        value={this.state.email}
                        label='Email'
                        placeHolder='Enter email to login'
                        onChangeText={() => { email => this.setState({ email }) }}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                </CardSection>


                <CardSection>
                    <Button>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
};
```

**Input.js**

```
const Input = ({ onChangeText, value, label, placeHolder }) => {

     return (
         <View>
             <Text>{label}</Text>
             <TextInput
                 autoCorrect={false}
                 value={value}
                 style={styles.textInputStyle}
                 placeholder={placeHolder}
                 onChangeText={onChangeText} />
         </View>
     ); };
```

**EDIT**
The solution from the comment below worked

I had to replace:

`onChangeText={() => { email => this.setState({ email }) }}`

to

```
onChangeText={ (email) => this.setState({ email }) }
```

Comment: Error can be in here: `onChangeText={() => { email => this.setState({ email }) }}`. Switch it to: `onChangeText={ (email) => this.setState({ email }) }`

Comment: Awesome! That works. Understood my mistake.